# Enrich callback not being called in OpenTelemetry.net, SqlClient

Tags: c#, sqlclient, open-telemetry

This is on .NET 6.

So I've added an enrich callback with the purpose of adding each parameter as a tag:

```
 appBuilder.Services.AddOpenTelemetryTracing((builder) =>
        
        builder
            .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
            .SetSampler(new AlwaysOnSampler())
            .AddSqlClientInstrumentation(options =>
            {
                options.SetDbStatementForText = true;
                options.SetDbStatementForStoredProcedure = true;
                options.RecordException = true;
                options.EnableConnectionLevelAttributes = true;
                options.Enrich = (activity, eventName, rawObject) =>
                {
                    if (eventName.Equals("OnCustom"))
                    {
                        activity.SetTag("ParametersAdded", "true");
                        if (rawObject is SqlCommand cmd)
                        {
                            foreach (SqlParameter parameter in cmd.Parameters)
                            {
                                activity.SetTag(parameter.ParameterName, parameter.Value.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
            })
            .AddZipkinExporter(options =>
            {
                options.Endpoint = new Uri(appBuilder.Configuration["TraceExporterUrl"]);

            }));
```

I'm getting the export in Zipkin, but it's not added the tags, and it doesn't seem to be hitting that Enrich callback at all - the ParametersAdded tag isn't being hit either. Can't figure out why this isn't working - Have I fundamentally misunderstood something?

Answer (score 0):

The Enrich is not called for activities that don't have the **IsAllDataRequested** property set to **true**.